# Scanf in c seems to require double input?

Tags: c

This is probably a really basic question but has me stumped so here goes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float argument = 8.86;
    printf("%f%\n", argument);
    argument = 7.75;
    printf("%f%\n", argument);
    scanf("%f%\n", &argument);
    printf("%f%\n", argument);
    return 0;
}
```

I just wrote this code to help me figure out whats going on. Basically, the scanf seems to require me to put any number then press enter as expected, but then enter another number and press enter or just press enter (after which it will then print the value put the FIRST time time). Shouldn't the code just immediately print the entered number and finish?

Could anyone explain how or why this is happening, thanks!

Comment: The `"\n"`in `scanf("%f%\n", &argument);` is also something that likely should be dropped as well as the `%` after the `%f`.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `%` in `scanf()` and `printf()` calls. `scanf()` attempts to intrepret it as additional conversion character. This results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remove them.

If you want to print `%` sign, use `%%`.

E.g.:

```
printf("%f%%\n", argument);
```

Comment: I am a complete moron...thanks for pointing this out. I haven't coded in about 3 months and this is what happens clearly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an extra `%` in `printf()` and `scanf()` function;
Second, you should not have `\n` in `scanf()` function; 
if have the `\n`, the console will ignore new line, space and all blank characters when you input.

Maybe like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float argument = 8.86;
    printf("%f\n", argument);
    argument = 7.75;
    printf("%f\n", argument);
    scanf("%f", &argument);
    printf("%f\n", argument);
    return 0;
}
```

I am also a beginner in C language. We come together!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str1[20], str2[30];

   printf("Enter String 1: ");
   scanf("%s", &str1);

   printf("Enter your String 2: ");
   scanf("%s", &str2);

   printf("String 1: %s\n", str1);
   printf("String 2:%s", str2);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are passing the wrong type to scanf: `scanf("%s", &str1);` `%s` specifier requires a `char*` argument yet the code passes a `char(*)[20]`.

Comment: LOL What? char* is the same of char[20] and char*[20] points to a matrix.

Comment: I sense some confusion from your comment. Here are some C basics: `char*` is a pointer to a char. `char[20]` is an array of 20 char. `char*[20]` is an array of 20 pointers to a char. `char(*)[20]` is a pointer to an array of 20 char.

Comment: What is a pointer to a char pointer? A Matrix of char. Learn 2 C

Comment: No, a pointer to pointer to a char, is just that, a pointer. You code is nevertheless, wrong. I see you are not trying to understand or listen to my attempts at teaching you, which you are free to do, so I will stop.  I'm ending this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**Only change in scan function **

from scan(%d\n)
to

Comment: my answer is correct and shortest
direct to problem
it is helpful ?

Comment: Your answer is missing something. To what should we change `scan(%d\n)`?